# Как добавить строку сумма в Django Inline Model Admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-template

У меня есть такие модели:

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
    object = models.ForeignKey(Object, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    count = models.IntegerField('Количество', null=True, blank=True)

class EquipmentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Equipment

class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', )
    inlines = [EquipmentInline]
```

Я хочу добавить строку **Сумма**, в которой будет считаться суммарное количество по столбцу **Количество**.
Смотрел это решение [django-admin: Add extra row with totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541956/django-admin-add-extra-row-with-totals), но оно работает только для `ModelAdmin` и не работает для `TabularInline`.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос таким способом:
Создал templatetag
admin_totals.py

```
from django import template
from django.db.models import Sum
from objects.models import Object, Equipment

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('admin/edit_inline/tabular_totals_results.html', 
takes_context=True)
def equipment_totals(context):
    object_id = context['object_id']
    object_ = Object.objects.get(id=object_id)
    equipments = Equipment.objects.filter(object=object_)
    total = equipments.aggregate(Sum('count')).get('count__sum')
    return {
        'total': total if total else 0,
    }
```

equipment_tabular.html
Взял файл tabular.html из Django и добавил в него

```
 ...
 </tr></thead>

 {% block result_list %}
 {% endblock %}

 <tbody>
 ...
```

tabular_totals.html

```
{% extends 'admin/edit_inline/equipment_tabular.html' %}
{% load admin_totals %}

{% block result_list %}
{% equipment_totals %}
{% endblock %}
```

tabular_totals_results.html

```
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <td>Итого: </td>
    <td>{{ total }}</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
```